# How can make a directive global so can be used anywhere at the page not fully controlled by angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-directives

Is there a way  to make a directive global? i need one to be added  from anywhere on the page not fully controlled by angular 2 example: 
I want to create (date picker , grid or image list ...etc) created by angular 2 and then use this component anywhere at the page created by other framwork similar to this kind of HTML:

```
<body>
    <label>birth of date</label>
    <input type= "text" id='dob' angular2datetimepicker  >
    <label>Join Date</label>
    <input type= "text" id= 'jod' angular2datetimepicker  > 
</body>
```

Where `angular2datetimepicker` is a component or custom directive created in angular 2, but used outside angular 2 scope.

Answer (score 2):

You could `bootstrap` it using [`PLATFORM_DIRECTIVES`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/PLATFORM_DIRECTIVES-let.html):

> A token that can be provided when bootstraping an application to make an array of directives available in every component of the application.
>
> ```
> import {PLATFORM_DIRECTIVES} from 'angular2/core';
> import {OtherDirective} from './myDirectives';
> @Component({
>   selector: 'my-component',
>   template: `
>     <!-- can use other directive even though the component does not list it in `directives` -->
>     <other-directive></other-directive>
>   `
> })
> export class MyComponent {
>   ...
> }
> bootstrap(MyComponent, [provide(PLATFORM_DIRECTIVES, {useValue: [OtherDirective], multi:true})]);
> ```

Running example below:

```
import {bootstrap}    from 'angular2/platform/browser';
import {PLATFORM_DIRECTIVES, provide}    from 'angular2/core';
import {HighlightDirective} from './highlight.directive';
import {AppComponent} from './app.component';

bootstrap(AppComponent, [
        provide(PLATFORM_DIRECTIVES, {useValue: HighlightDirective, multi: true})
]);
```

See [**demo plunker here**](http://plnkr.co/edit/pQbCVLvVSq79bB4fmaHF?p=preview).

Comment: thanks @acdcjunior, but at my situations the directive should be added at the main page - index.html-  because there is other framework that control mainly this page and contains other elements that I cannot move it to the componenent.html .

Comment: What other framework? If you have those requirements, maybe you could add the object that controls to the `window` object, and then reference it when `bootstrap()`ing.

Comment: Thanks for this, I get a warning WARNING: sanitizing unsafe style value function () {
        return (this.layout === 'column') ? 'column' : 'row';
    } (see http://g.co/ng/security#xss). Is there an update to this for Angular 2.0.0?